# Query always returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, logic

So the problem is the $check variable is always NULL, even though there is already a record in the database that match the SELECT statement I have written, it's still null. I know it's simple enough but i can't find the error. I already tried using empty, isNull, ====, but the problem is the $check is always null. Why it is always null?.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM linkedin_lookup WHERE "
              ."`given-name`='{$table['given_name']}' && "
              ."`family-name`='{$table['family_name']}' && "
              ."`location`='{$table['location']}' && "
              ."`industry`='{$table['industry']}' && "
              ."`headline`='{$table['headline']}'";
        $results = $db->query($sql);
        $check = $results->num_rows;
        if ($check):
            echo "Record already exist";
        else:
            $sql = "INSERT INTO linkedin_lookup (`given-name`,`family-name`,`location`,`industry`,`headline`,`date_search`) "
            ."VALUES "
            ."('{$table['given_name']}',"
            ."'{$table['family_name']}',"
            ."'{$table['location']}',"
            ."'{$table['industry']}',"
            ."'{$table['headline']}',"
            ."'{$now}')";
            $db->query($sql);
            echo "Succesfully inserted record(s)" . '<br />';
        endif;
```

UPDATE MY CODE TO REFLECT INPUTS, but still it accepts duplicate. Is my SELECT STATEMENT wrong?. I put && right so it;s supposed to scan all fields if the same.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: Which DB extension are you using, `mysqli`?

Comment: I don't like this character ` in php script. Sometimes it caused issues earlier for me.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes sir, mysqli. My problem is why it's null. When i echo the $sql and query in the database, it has a results. I tried the $db->affected_rows. It's still NULL.

@MuhammedHedayet if i dont use the character `, it gives me errors.

Comment: if you var_dump($results) is there actually data in it?

Comment: It is NULL because your query fails or you must return result object in your `$db->query` function. Correct would be: `$result = $db->query() ; if ($result && $result->num_rows >= 1) { echo "ASD" ;}`

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet: silly comment. note the OP's `given-name` and `family-name` fields. without backticks. those would be interpreted as math: "family minus name" and "given minus name".

Comment: @KyleK - if i var_dump($results), the output is " resource(4) of type (mysql result) ". I assumed there is?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you call `num_rows` on the result of the query (same for `fetch_assoc`), NOT the array.

```
$results = $db->query($sql);
$check = $results->num_rows;
if( $check) {
    echo "Record already exists";
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT.....";
}
```

Note that you could just try to insert it up front and check `affected_rows` - if it's zero then it faied to insert due to already existing. Note that you'll need a `UNIQUE KEY` on the table in the right fields.

Comment: Hello sir, i've tried your snippet. But the value is still null. I can't seem to understand this simple statement :/

Answer (score 0):

If `$results` does infact contain something....and the query is infact working, which I dunno if it is....

You could just try this instead....

```
 $db->query($sql);
    $results = $db->fetch_assoc();

    if (count($results) > 0):
        //echo "Record already exist";
    else:
```

Comment: Ok sir, i've change my code to you, but then I truncated the table so there is no entries present, but it tells me that "Record already exist" even if there is no record.

Comment: Well @Kolinks suggestion should have worked, so it really depends on your query calss then, and what its outputting....

Comment: I tried the suggestion of @Kolinks the i put a var_dump on $results and $check. Then i run it.

resource(4) of type (mysql result) = Result of $results 
NULL = Result of $check

Answer (score 0):

Ok now it works, i think the class $db is not mysqli, because we are using a framework that is developed by the company. So my codes now as follows and It works.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM linkedin_lookup WHERE "
          ."`given-name`='{$table['given_name']}' && "
          ."`family-name`='{$table['family_name']}' && "
          ."`location`='{$table['location']}' && "
          ."`industry`='{$table['industry']}' && "
          ."`headline`='{$table['headline']}'";
    $db->query($sql);
    $check = $db->fetch_array();
    if ($check):
        echo "Record already exist";
    else:
        $sql = "INSERT INTO linkedin_lookup (`given-name`,`family-name`,`location`,`industry`,`headline`,`date_search`) "
        ."VALUES "
        ."('{$table['given_name']}',"
        ."'{$table['family_name']}',"
        ."'{$table['location']}',"
        ."'{$table['industry']}',"
        ."'{$table['headline']}',"
        ."'{$now}')";
        $db->query($sql);
        echo "Succesfully inserted record(s)" . '<br />';
    endif;
```